# (angularjs 1.3.9) uncaught illegal access while adding new items to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that is falling out of sync and returning "uncaught illegal access" when trying to add new items to it from the controller.

The controller scope array I am using to populate the ng-repeat is getting updated perfectly fine, but something gets lost along the way.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="list-item" 
                ng-include="'queue/' + item.type.parent + '.html'"></div>
```

My controller function pushing new data to it:

```
public addNotification(type: string): void {

        switch(type) {
            case "itemOne":
                this.scope.items.unshift(this.service.scope.itemOne);
            break;
            case "itemTwo":
                this.scope.items.unshift(this.service.scope.itemTwo);
            break;
            case "itemThree":
                this.scope.items.unshift(this.service.scope.itemThree);
            break;
            case "itemFour":
                this.scope.items.unshift(this.service.scope.itemFour);
            break;
        }
        // remove item from array after hiding
        this.timeout((): void => {
            // these properties return illegal access
            this.scope.items[0].expand = true;
            this.scope.items[0].visible = true;
        }, 250);
    }
```

My service Object supplying the data:

```
this.scope.itemOne =  {
                      type: {
                          parent: 'itemOne'
                      },
                      // a bunch of json data
                      expand: false,
                      visible: true,
                      focus: true
                  };
```

The controller gets the data fine from my service and the controllers items property has the populated list I expect, but again ng-repeat fails to update.

This problem arises when I try to add duplicate json data from the service into the controller. Controller gets it and stores it how I expect on this.scope.items but ng-repeat doesnt like duplicates for some reason.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your exact issue, (sorry confused after readin the question) illegal access error or duplicate in repeater? Can you prepare a simple demo

Comment: hmm, duplicate data in ng-repeat is not liked by angular as-is; however, the error is usually as described here: [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) ..just to test out if the same solution MAY work, can you do this to your ng-repeat: `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`?

Comment: @Shehryar Thanks for the response, reading the docs that certainly sounds like my problem. I will give that solution a try and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

So after checking Shehryar Abbasi's answer it was the fact that ng-repeat was tracking the items in the list by value. telling it to track by $index like so:

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
```

I am now able to insert duplicate data into the loop no problem without access errors.